# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed and v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath on POD under Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, memory, heap-memory

I'm running Microservices on a K8S Cluster and one of my Microservices has between 4-6 pods.

It keeps throwing the following:

```
v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
```

And:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I'm using NODE JS on the Backend.

From Googling this issue I've found that people suggested to do

```
NODE_OPTIONS
  --max-old-space-size=8000
```

However the problem doesn't stop , after my app is running for some time (20-30 minutes) and the pods start doing their job , the memory starts increasing until it reaches the Maximum I've dedicated to the POD (8GB) and then is restarts.

Why is this still happening ? Why `--max-old-space-size=8192` doesn't solve the heap issue ?

Comment: Is your code accumulating memory without limit?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Wondering if you have resource constraints specified for your pod. What are the params for request/limit and what memory level the heap limit allocation is failing at in nodejs